# React.js - Using axios with context and reducer

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to React so hopefully this is something easy. I'm getting some API data and attempting to update the context using a reducer, then having a child component update with the retrieved data from the API.

I create an empty context in context.tsx:

```
export const AppStateContext = createContext(null);
```

My context provider then uses useEffect() to make a get call using axios to my API:

```
const [context, dispatch] = useReducer(AppContextReducer, {});

React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    fetchData();
});

const fetchData = async () => {
    try {           
        axios.get('https://run.mocky.io/v3/685895a0-6f3b-446f-ae29-9157a4f5d733')
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({ action: "SET_CONTEXT", payload: response.data });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}


return (
    <AppStateContext.Provider value={{ context, dispatch }}>
        {props.children}
    </AppStateContext.Provider>
)
```

Reducer:

```
const AppContextReducer = (state, e) => {
    switch (e.action) {
        case "SET_CONTEXT":
            return e.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

And my child component:

```
export const User = () => {
    const { context, update } = React.useContext(AppStateContext);

    return (
        <div className="title">{context && context.ActiveUser && context.ActiveUser.Name}</div>
    )
}
```

If I take out the checks in the child component (remove context && context.ActiveUser), then I get an error that context.ActiveUser is undefined. But if I log the context to the console, it's there. So I'm guessing either I'm not formatting the context object correctly or I'm not returning the data in the correct format (it's all done in JSON) from the API. The `context.ActiveUser.Name` is never rendered to the page.

This is a very slimmed down version of what I'm ultimately trying to achieve. The context itself will be much larger so a reducer will be necessary to update all the individual properties.

I have a full working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/app-react-minimal-60eow?file=/src/components/dashboard/navigation/squares/user.js:121-490

I appreciate any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you need to add the check while using context is because your value is initially an empty object in `User` component at the time of initial render which is expected since you define the initial value of `useReducer` to be an empty object.

After an initial render, `useEffect` in your `ContextProvider` is executed and you `fetchData` is called which fetches data from the API and updates the result. NNow a re-render is triggered due to update in state of reducer and the User component gets the updated state from context. At this time the fetched data is available and you can access `context.ActiveUser.Name`

Now the reason you don't see the Name in screen is because the API is returning you a string instead of JSON object which is why `context.ActiveUser` is `undefined` on it

Also you must call fetchData within useEffect which runs on some specified condition such as initial render and not on every render

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("useEffect");
    fetchData();
}, []); // Call useEffect on initial render only
```

Comment: Right, but why does the value of context.ActiveUser.Name never show up?

Comment: That is because response received from server is not JSON object but a string. You need to make sure your API is sending you JSON response so that you can access its individual properties

Comment: Thanks. I modified the JSON from the mock api and that fixed that problem. Now I'm just stuck with an infinite loop in useEffect. Haha...thanks again

Comment: @TPeel I had updated my answer about the infinite loop in useEffect too. You should pass a second argument to control execution time of useEffect

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the help.